# Get value of the list from another class

Tags: c#, json

im trying to get song info, which is parsed from JSON file.
Here is my `Music` class to parse and write data to `List<TrackData>`

```
public class Music
{
    [DataContract]
    public class TrackData
    {
        [DataMember]
        public int id { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public int owner_id { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string artist { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string title { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public int duration { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string url { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public int genre_id { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public int? lyrics_id { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public int? album_id { get; set; }
    }

    [DataContract]
    public class JsonData
    {
        [DataMember]
        public int count { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public List<TrackData> items { get; set; }
    }

    [DataContract]
    public class JsonResponse
    {
        [DataMember]
        public JsonData response { get; set; }
    }

    public static JsonResponse Deserialize(String Json)
    {
        DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(JsonResponse));
        MemoryStream stream1 = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Json));
        JsonResponse result = (JsonResponse)ser.ReadObject(stream1);
        return result;
    }
}
```

So far, im able to get data through:

```
Music.JsonResponse Response = Music.Deserialize(await GetAudio()); // This is working like a charm, so no need to rewrite this function
Music.JsonData Data = Response.response; // Assigning Parsed JSON to the class and later to TrackData
Music.TrackData Track = Data.items.FirstOrDefault(); // I need data for all of the tracks, not only for the first one
MessageDialog ResultDialog = new MessageDialog(Track.artist); // So im getting only first value of the List
ResultDialog.ShowAsync();
```

I want to assign this List to a normal list, but not able to do it, instead of titles im just getting `AsemblyName.Namespace.Music+TrackData` for 100 records (in my local library)

So i want to place all the values to a string (Each song with all the data in one string), and to be able to get data for all the songs, not just first one

Tried many things, but nothing seems to help. Sorry for this question, maybe its relatively easy, but i'm kind of newbie in C#

Thanks in advance.

Comment: First of all, are you sure that your Json data file is intact (open it in a text editor and validate). Second, you are speaking about "assign this List to a normal list, but not able to do it" - show what you have tried. Third, why do you want to put all information regarding one song into one huge string, especially since your class TrackData already provides those neat properties?

Comment: Retagged. It doesn't seem to have anything to do with WPF or Metro design language.